# Finding linear map given a condition.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Given that $T:\mathbb{R}^{2}\to\mathbb{R}^{2}$ is linear and
$T(3,2) =(4,6)$ and $T (2,3) =(1,-1)$ ,how can I find $T (4,3)$ ?.

Comment: What have you tried, and what are you having trouble with? Have you seen any similar examples, or other problems where the linearity of $T$ is important?

Comment: Try writing $(4,3)$ as a linear combination of $(3,2)$ and $(2,3)$. Then apply $T$ to both sides and use linearity.

Comment: I know the conditions for a linear map , t(x+y) =t(x) +t(y)

Comment: and t(cv) = ct(v) for a scalar c

Comment: So am I trying to solve (4,3) = a(4,6)+b(2,3) ? .

Comment: (4,6) is one of your outputs, not one of the input vectors.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\langle 3, 2 \rangle$ and $\langle 2, 3 \rangle$ are linearly independent.  Therefore, their span is all of $\mathbb{R}^2$.  In particular, $\langle 4, 3 \rangle$ can be written as a linear combination of $\langle 3, 2 \rangle$ and $\langle 2, 3 \rangle$.

Do this, and apply the fact that $T(c\textbf{v}) = c T(\textbf{v})$ for all $c \in \mathbb{R}$ and $T(\textbf{v} + \textbf{w}) = T(\textbf{v}) + T(\textbf{w})$.

(Those two properties are universal for all linear transformations.)

Comment: ....And now that I get around to reading the comments, it looks like Jimmy's a lot faster than I am (+1).

Comment: Thanks very much, got it now.